# How to fill an external area of ​a marked region in an image using opencv?

Tags: java, android, image, opencv, kotlin

I am developing an application using kotlin and opencv. The application has an image segmentation step in which the user marks a region of interest which I need to fill in the entire outside of that region with black. I'm taking the coordinates of the marked region and using floodFill to fill the image. However, with the code below it ends up filling the whole image, and not just the external region of the mark.

Code:

```
private fun extractBackground(coordinates: Coordinates, currentPhotoPath: String): String {
    // TODO: Provide complex object that has both path and extension

    val width: Int
    val height: Int
    width = bitmap.getWidth()
    height = bitmap.getHeight()
    val rect = Rect(coordinates.first, coordinates.second)
    val rgba = Mat()
    val gray_mat = Mat()
    val threeChannel = Mat()

    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, gray_mat)

    Imgproc.cvtColor(gray_mat, rgba, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)

    Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba, threeChannel, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    val mask = Mat.zeros(rgba.rows() + 2, rgba.cols() + 2, CvType.CV_8UC1)

    Imgproc.floodFill(rgba, mask, Point(0.0, 0.0), Scalar(255.0), rect, Scalar(0.0), Scalar(0.0), 4 + (255 shl 8) + Imgproc.FLOODFILL_MASK_ONLY)
    Core.subtract(mask, Scalar.all(0.0), mask)
    val roi = Rect(1, 1, rgba.cols() - 2, rgba.rows() - 2)

    val temp = Mat()
    mask.submat(roi).copyTo(temp)
    Imgcodecs.imwrite(currentPhotoPath + "_tmp.png", temp)

    return currentPhotoPath
}
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

can someone help me fix this?

Comment: copy the roi containing the coins on a black image

Comment: As @Miki mentioned: Crop the green roi of the `Input` image and paste it on a black canvas same size as your  `Input` matrix. Use the same location given by your green rectangle.

Comment: can you help me do this in the code, please do not know how it is